# Jetty Virtual Hosts

Tags: virtualhost, jetty, domain

I'm trying to configure Jetty with multiple domains, the problem I'm facing is that Jetty is running withing another server product called SmartfoxServer, so I'm not really sure if i can actually configure it the way i like.

This is my jetty.xml:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="ThreadPool">

      <New class="org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        <Set name="lowThreads">20</Set>
        <Set name="SpawnOrShrinkAt">2</Set>
      </New>

      <!-- Optional Java 5 bounded threadpool with job queue 
      <New class="org.mortbay.thread.concurrent.ThreadPool">
        <Set name="corePoolSize">50</Set>
        <Set name="maximumPoolSize">50</Set>
      </New>
      -->
    </Set>



    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set connectors                                              -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- One of each type!                                           -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->

    <!-- Use this connector for many frequently idle connections
         and for threadless continuations.
    -->    
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- Use this connector if NIO is not available. 
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector">
            <Set name="port">8081</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
    -->

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <!-- To add a HTTPS SSL listener                                     -->
    <!-- see jetty-ssl.xml to add an ssl connector. use                  -->
    <!-- java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-ssl.xml             -->
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <!-- To allow Jetty to be started from xinetd                        -->
    <!-- mixin jetty-xinetd.xml:                                         -->
    <!--   java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-xinetd.xml        -->
    <!--                                                                 -->
    <!-- See jetty-xinetd.xml for further instructions.                  -->
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set up global session ID manager                            -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!--
    <Set name="sessionIdManager">
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionIdManager">
        <Set name="workerName">node1</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
    -->

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set handler Collection Structure                            --> 
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="RequestLog" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure the context deployer                              -->
    <!-- A context deployer will deploy contexts described in        -->
    <!-- configuration files discovered in a directory.              -->
    <!-- The configuration directory can be scanned for hot          -->
    <!-- deployments at the configured scanInterval.                 -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- This deployer is configured to deploy contexts configured   -->
    <!-- in the $JETTY_HOME/contexts directory                       -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
          <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
          <Set name="configurationDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts</Set>
          <Set name="scanInterval">5</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure the webapp deployer.                              -->
    <!-- A webapp  deployer will deploy standard webapps discovered  -->
    <!-- in a directory at startup, without the need for additional  -->
    <!-- configuration files.    It does not support hot deploy or   -->
    <!-- non standard contexts (see ContextDeployer above).          -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- This deployer is configured to deploy webapps from the      -->
    <!-- $JETTY_HOME/webapps directory                               -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Normally only one type of deployer need be used.            -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
          <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
          <Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/www</Set>
      <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">false</Set>
      <Set name="extract">true</Set>
      <Set name="allowDuplicates">false</Set>
          <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/config/jetty/webdefault.xml</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure Authentication Realms                             -->
    <!-- Realms may be configured for the entire server here, or     -->
    <!-- they can be configured for a specific web app in a context  -->
    <!-- configuration (see $(jetty.home)/contexts/test.xml for an   -->
    <!-- example).                                                   -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="UserRealms">
      <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.security.UserRealm">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.HashUserRealm">
            <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/config/jetty/realm.properties</Set>
            <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure Request Log                                       -->
    <!-- Request logs  may be configured for the entire server here, -->
    <!-- or they can be configured for a specific web app in a       -->
    <!-- contexts configuration (see $(jetty.home)/contexts/test.xml -->
    <!-- for an example).                                            -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Ref id="RequestLog">
      <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
          <Set name="filename"><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs/http"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
          <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
          <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
          <Set name="append">true</Set>
          <Set name="extended">false</Set>
          <Set name="logCookies">false</Set>
          <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
    </Ref>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra options                                               -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
    <Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
</Configure>
```

I have the following folder structure:

- www/
- www/root/
- www/domain2/

**localhost:8080 loads** root/index.html

**localhost:8080/domain2/** loads domain2/index.html

In the root and domain2 folders, there's this WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>default</display-name>
    <description></description>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.py</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.htm</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.python.util.PyServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>python.home</param-name>
            <param-value>./lib/</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.py</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I've tried adding:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/www/domain2/</Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>domain2</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

to the web.xml file and then accessing it with http://domain2:8080, but that's not working and I'm really not sure if this is the right way to do it. The information here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts is referring to a war, but I don't even have a war. And as said, I'm not even sure if it's possible, since I'm using Jetty within SmartfoxServer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify what _"but that's not working"_ means?

Comment: Sure, thanks for asking. So I'm adding the "org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" code into the web.xml just above the </web-app> line. By nothing happens i mean that i cannot access the website through http://domain2:8080. Firefox loads forever, just as if i would enter http://AnyRandomString:8080. By the way I'm using Jetty 6.1.26. The version cannot be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok i solved it by:

1. creating a contexts folder at the same level as the www folder.
2. creating the following domain2.xml file in the contexts folder (don't forget to add the xml header)

> **'put the xml header here'**
>
> ```
> <!-- ==================================================================
> Configure and deploy the test web application in $(jetty.home)/webapps/test
>
> Note. If this file did not exist or used a context path other that /test
> then the default configuration of jetty.xml would discover the test
> webapplication with a WebAppDeployer.  By specifying a context in this
> directory, additional configuration may be specified and hot deployments 
> detected.
> ===================================================================== -->
>
> <Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
>
>   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
>   <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                       -->
>   <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
>   <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
>   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
>   <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
>  <!--   <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/www</Set> -->
>     <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/www/domain2/</Set>
>    <!--     <Set name="handler">
>         <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ResourceHandler">
>                 <Set name="welcomeFiles">
>                 <Array type="String">
>                         <Item>index.html</Item>
>                 </Array>
>             </Set>
>         </New> 
>     </Set> -->
>   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
>   <!-- Optional context configuration                         -->
>   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
>   <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/config/jetty/webdefault.xml</Set>
>   <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/www/domain2/WEB-INF/web.xml</Set>
>
>
>   <!-- virtual hosts -->
>   <Set name="virtualHosts">
>     <Array type="String">
>       <Item>domain2.com</Item>
>       <Item>www.domain2.com</Item>
>     </Array>
>   </Set>
> </Configure>
> ```